# Trouble Applying Animations Sequentially using Action Editor - T-Pose Not Responding as Expected

Tags: animation, armature

I am currently experiencing a strange problem with the Action Editor in Blender 4.0.2.

I have a skinned T-Pose character and two skinless animations: Idle, and Walk, all Mixamo downloads; I want to apply the animations in sequence to the T-Pose character using Blender's NLA.

Once in the Action Editor, I renamed all the actions to coherent names; then I selected  the T-Pose character (no animation data), and in the Action Editor Actions drop-down I chose the "Idle" action:

[image: screenshot of Action Editor after changing the action for that armature]

As you can see, the action was switched as evidenced by the key-frames in the Action Editor's Timeline summary (the T-Pose had no animation data). However, this action doesn't seem to affect the T-Pose armature in any discernible way; in all the tutorials I've followed concerning this process at this stage the T-Pose should take the pose of the new action's first frame; this does not happen. When I play the animation, the character remains in T-Pose, while the other actions play normally. Also, if I Push Down the action, it shows in NLA just as expected; but if I play the animation, the character remains in A-Pose, without animation data.

[image: Push Down and Warning]

It fails with the following warning: "WARNING: User property type 'Short' is not supported". I have tried everything I could think of! Is Blender 4.0.2 Action Editor broken, or have I missed something?

Comment: If you provide a file, I'll probably take a look at it.  All the things you're expecting are things you should expect.  So something's not what you expected it to be-- or, Blender's bugging.  But, probably, Blender's not bugging,  But, only probably.

Comment: Hi Nathan, 

Yeah, sure, thank you for taking the time..  Please find the link  [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1waegKIJyPZM51QQBlBcqobwaCBbAnh_8/view?usp=drive_link). 

Thanks in advance for all your insights. 

Sept

Comment: Your link is showing "access denied."

Comment: Sorry, Nathan; I forgot to share with "Anyone with the Link"; here is the link to the BLEND file: 

[link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1waegKIJyPZM51QQBlBcqobwaCBbAnh_8/view?usp=sharing).

Once again thank you for all your help.

Sept

Answer (score 0):

The bone names are different.

The actions you are trying to use on the center rig in your file has animations on bones with names like "mixamorig:LeftForeArm".  Meanwhile, the bones in the center rig has bones with names like "mixamorig1:LeftForeArm".  That extra "1" in there makes all the difference: it means that your idle and walking actions don't animate any bones in the center rig, because no animated bones in those actions exist in the center rig.

Comment: Hi, Nathan

Thank you so much for your fast, relevant answer.

That's amazing; I wonder why the bones have different names, since all were downloaded  from the same source! This is one of the reasons why I didn't check the naming convention. 

Just a final question: can I change the names to whatever, as long as the names are the same? (I'd like to change the "mixamo" to something less intrusive like mx.RightUpLeg, etc..

Sept

Comment: @user3350 The bone names are linked to actions (as you've already discovered) but also to vertex groups on meshes-- it is the correspondence of names that creates the weights.  You can change bone names to your heart's content, provided that you also update the names of vertex groups on meshes.  Renaming the bones in edit or pose mode will automatically adjust the names of vertex groups for parented, armature deformed meshes, but there are bugs when you rename a bone to a name for which there is already an existing vertex group.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I am currently testing the names against each other; I'll get back to you later with results. Thank you and have a great weekend. Sept

Comment: Hi Nathan,

Just a brief comment to let you know everything worked just as you explained and the issue can be labeled as resolved. 

This is the best support session I've ever had, you just gave me the info I needed to solve the issue and learn a ton about Blender's Animation and its singular tool: The Action Editor in the process. I don't fully understand why the bones were named differently, since I downloaded both in the same Mixamo session!

Enjoy the rest of the weekend!

Sept